# Timing constraints in UML 2.5

Tags: uml

The UML 1.1 specification discusses timing constraints for Sequence Diagrams, whilst I cannot find a similar construct in the UML 2.5 specification for Interaction Diagrams. Did timing constraints get removed from UML in later versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UML 2.5 still got timing constraint where you can find it at **Section 17.2 Interaction** (see Figure 17.5).

[image]

Comment: Wow, how I didn’t see that in the spec I have no idea! Thank you for your help!!